# Count occurrences of a word in a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, count

I'm making a search function for my website, which finds relevant results from a database.  I'm looking for a way to count occurrences of a word, but I need to ensure that there are word boundaries on both sides of the word ( so I don't end up with "triple" when I want "rip").

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

People have misunderstood my question:

How can I count the number of such occurences ***within a single row?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the sort of thing that relational databases are very good at, unless you can use fulltext indexing, and you have already stated that you cannot, since you're using InnoDB. I'd suggest selecting your relevant rows and doing the word count in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this perverted way:

```
SELECT 
(LENGTH(field) - LENGTH(REPLACE(field, 'word', ''))) / LENGTH('word') AS `count`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

- This query can be very slow
- It looks pretty ugly
- REPLACE() is case-sensitive

Comment: This will count *strings*, not *words*.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome the issue of mysql's case-sensitive `REPLACE()` function by using `LOWER()`.

Its sloppy, but on my end this query runs pretty fast.

To speed things along I retrieve the resultset in a select which I have declared as a derived table in my 'outer' query. Since mysql already has the results at this point, the replace method works pretty quickly.

I created a query similar to the one below to search for multiple terms in multiple tables and multiple columns. I obtain a 'relevance' number equivalent to the sum of the count of all occurrances of all found search terms in all columns searched

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( 
((length(x.ent_title) - length(replace(LOWER(x.ent_title),LOWER('there'),''))) / length('there')) 
+ ((length(x.ent_content) - length(replace(LOWER(x.ent_content),LOWER('there'),''))) / length('there'))
 + ((length(x.ent_title) - length(replace(LOWER(x.ent_title),LOWER('another'),''))) / length('another')) 
+ ((length(x.ent_content) - length(replace(LOWER(x.ent_content),LOWER('another'),''))) / length('another')) 
) as relevance, 
x.ent_type, 
x.ent_id, 
x.this_id as anchor,
page.page_name
FROM ( 
(SELECT 
'Foo' as ent_type, 
sp.sp_id as ent_id, 
sp.page_id as this_id, 
sp.title as ent_title, 
sp.content as ent_content,
sp.page_id as page_id
FROM sp
WHERE (sp.title LIKE '%there%' OR sp.content LIKE '%there%' OR sp.title LIKE '%another%' OR sp.content LIKE '%another%' ) AND (sp_content.title NOT LIKE '%goes%' AND sp_content.content NOT LIKE '%goes%')
) UNION (
  [search a different table here.....]
)
) as x
JOIN page ON page.page_id = x.page_id 
WHERE page.rstatus = 'ACTIVE'
ORDER BY relevance DESC, ent_title;
```

Hope this helps someone

-- Seacrest out

Comment: This will count *strings*, not *words*.

Answer (score 1):

create a user defined function like this and use it in your query

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `getCount`(myStr VARCHAR(1000), myword VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE (result > 0) DO
    SET result = INSTR(myStr, myword);
    IF(result > 0) THEN 
        SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        SET myStr = SUBSTRING(myStr, result + LENGTH(myword));
    END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN cnt;    

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope it helps
[Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892133/how-to-get-frequency-of-a-word-in-a-row-using-mysql-fulltext/17889371#17889371)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

select count(*) from table where fieldname REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';

The gory details are in the MySQL manual, section 11.4.2.

Comment: This checks how many rows contain the search string. The questioner wants to count how often the search string is contained in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like LIKE or REGEXP will not scale (unless it's a leftmost prefix match).

Consider instead using a **[fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)** for what you want to do.

```
select count(*) from yourtable where match(title, body) against ('some_word');
```

Comment: Can't do fulltext index... I'm using InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the technique as described in the link below. The method uses `length` and `replace` functions of MySQL.

[Keyword Relevance](http://r937.com/keyword_relevance.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a search I would advise something like Sphinx or Lucene, I find Sphinx (as an independent full text indexer) to be a lot easier to set up and run. It runs fast, and generates the indexes very fast. Even if you were using MyISAM I would suggest using it, it has a lot more power than a full text index from MyISAM.

It can also integrate (somewhat) with MySQL.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on what DBMS you are using, some allow writing UDFs that could do this.