# count occurences of substring with limit on amounts of substring

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search an string on occurences of a substring. But I want to limit them to specific amounts to detect.

My angles VARCHAR looks  like this:

```
0,90,0,90,180,180,270,0,270,0,90
```

My first attempt was with a LIKE statement. But I cannot count the occurences then:

```
SELECT *   FROM anglesTable WHERE corners LIKE "%180%' AND corners LIKE "%270%'  LIMIT 1000
```

my second try was this:

```
 SELECT  *, foo.counts270,foo.counts180,foo.counts60 FROM 
   (
     SELECT anglesNew.*, 
            LENGTH( corners) - LENGTH(REPLACE(corners, '270', '')) AS counts270,
            LENGTH( corners) - LENGTH(REPLACE(corners, '180', '')) AS counts180, 
            LENGTH( corners) - LENGTH(REPLACE(corners, '60', '')) AS counts60 
     FROM anglesNew 
   ) as foo
```

But that is too slow.

I want to know if there's a more faster way to query this through a database of 3 million entries.

If there's a better way to search this kind of data, advise would be welcome.

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) might be the key here.

Comment: Why SELECT from subquery?Remove the outer select

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395810/count-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-row-in-mysql