# How to count the occurrence of a specific word in a Mysql db row?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to PHP. I want to count the occurrence of a specific word in a MySQL db row.
For example: There are two columns name and description.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| name | description                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| abcd | My name ***is*** abcd. My father's name ***is*** xyz |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| xyzt | My name ***is*** xyz. I am a good girl.              |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to count the occurrence of the word 'is' from the 1st row description column. In the above example, '***is***' occurs **twice** in the 1st row and **once** in the second row. Please guide me for the same.

Comment: For a SQL only answer, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field

Comment: NOT voting to close this as a duplicate of the question linked above, since that question asks about strings while this question explicitly asks about *words*

Comment: Try `select count(*) from yourtable where match(description) against ('is');` borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/396266/ or `select count(*) from table where fieldname REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/395859/

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of pure-SQL attempted solutions here on StackOverflow, but most of them count strings, not words. So [let's reiterate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274741/1446005):

**SQL in general, and MySQL in particular, is not the best fit for the job.** You'd better do it with PHP (if the result set is "small enough"):

```
$count = preg_match_all("/\\b$word\\b/", $input, &$matches);
```

[Alternative, richer solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2984800/1446005) exist based on [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Note that it *can* be achieved in pure SQL:

- [with a stored procedure like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754159/1446005).

  In this example, replace the regex with `[[:<:]]your_word[[:>:]]` to match a specific word. Then just `SELECT wordcount(your_column) FROM your_table`. Improve the procedure by adding an input paramter (the word to count occurrences of). Then* `RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]', input_parameter, '[[:>:]]')`.
- even without a stored procedure (but [with the help of an auxiliary table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411095/1446005)).

  In this example, replace `HAVING word <> ' '` with `HAVING word <> 'your_word'` to count a specific word. `GROUP BY word, maintable.id` (instead of just `word`) to get a detailed cound by row. Add `WHERE` clauses to filter out the rows. Drawback: only a spaces are recognised as word delimiters.

I suppose the benefit of going for a PHP-based solution is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Query for this:

```
SELECT name,(CHAR_LENGTH(description)-
        CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(description,'is','')))/CHAR_LENGTH('is') AS TotalCount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name
```

Result:

```
NAME    TOTALCOUNT
abcd    2
xyzt    1
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a4f/1)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Since this query also counts any words which contains is (like 'this'), we can query for ' is ' (with one space before and one after).

```
SELECT name,(CHAR_LENGTH(description)-
        CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(description,' is ','')))/CHAR_LENGTH(' is ') AS TotalCount
FROM TableName
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Neat, unfortunately this will also count 'this', 'isoceles' and 'prism'. And mysql does not (AFAIK) have a regex replacement function (regexes can describe word boundaries)

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply. Will try it out soon :)

Comment: This will miss "Do you know what my name is?" and "Is it Bob?"

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`substr_count`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
substr_count ( string $haystack , string $needle)
```

It counts the amount of occurrences of a word in a string.

Comment: I got it directly form here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: This counts *string* (not *word*) occurrences.`substr_count
('foobar', 'foo')` returns
`1`, but `0` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Pass all rows in array :

```
$query= "SELECT * from  yourtable "; 
$result= $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[]=$row;
}
```

And transform array in array with count :

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
$name=$row['name'];
$description=$row['description'];
$myarr[$name]=substr_count($description, 'is');
}
```

You obtain desired array :

```
abcd => 2
xyzt => 1
...
```